# Unix pattern datetime match

Tags: regex, linux, unix, awk, sed

I want to edit this line:

```
1987,4,12,31,4,1987-12-31 00:00:00.0000000,UA,19977,UA,,631,12197,1219701,31703,HPN,White Plains, NY,NY,36,New York,22,13930,1393001,30977,ORD,Chicago\, IL,IL,17,Illinois,41,756,802,483.2,6,6,0,0,0700-0759,,,,,914,938,600.8,24,24,1,1,0900-0959,0,,0,138,156,,1,738,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,US1NJBG0005,US1ILCK0027,,,,,,,,,,,,,1987-12-31 08:09:12.0000000,519494350
```

and i want the output to be :

1987,4,12,31,4,**1987-12-31 00:00:00.000**,UA,19977,UA,,631,12197,1219701,31703,HPN,White
Plains, NY,NY,36,New York,22,13930,1393001,30977,ORD,Chicago\, IL,IL,17,Illinois,41,756,802,483.2,6,6,0,0,0700-0759,,,,,914,938,600.8,24,24,1,1,0900-0959,0,,0,138,156,,1,738,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,US1NJBG0005,US1ILCK0027,,,,,,,,,,,,,**1987-12-31 08:09:12.000**,519494350

I want to find each pattern of: `****-**-** **:**:**.0000000`

and erase the last 4 digits ( 0000 ) so I get `****-**-** **:**:**.000.`

If its helpful this date format is in the 6th columns and the n-1 columns.

Comment: Note `I want` isn't a good format for an `SO` question. What have you tried? Hint `awk -F ','` and lookup `substr awk`

Comment: yes i tried everything , the problem is that i didn't succeeded to go to the specific columns and then make the change . i only manage to do awk '{sub(/....$/,"")}1' on some file with "1987-12-31 08:09:12.0000000" and the output was 1987-12-31 08:09:12.000 . but i can i do it on a delimited text file ?

Comment: With these types of question it's always trivial to find the text you want but much harder to exclude the text you DON'T want. Post a FEW lines of sample input (including any cases you think will be hard to deal with) plus expected output or you're likely to get a solution that works for that one line you posted but fails for others in future in your real data.

Comment: Look, obviously you're trying, but it's simple - post a FEW lines of input, not just 1, with the associated expected output and make sure both are formatted correctly.

Comment: never mind , this is the solution : awk --re-interval -F , '{sub("[0-9]{4}$", "", $6); sub("[0-9]{4}$", "", $(NF-1)); for(i=1; i<NF;i++) printf("%s,", $i); printf("%s\n", $NF)}'

Comment: It's extremely unlikely that that is the best solution. It uses string instead of RE delimiters in the sub()s, uses hard-coded values instead of character classes in the REs, it's puting unnecessary parentheses around the printf args, it's going to cause recompilation of your records, probably adding/removing spaces, etc. And you're working around using a VERY old gawk version instead of just getting a newer one. There's almost certainly a more robust and/or simpler solution out there once we understand your requirements better.

Answer (score 3):

To get the value of the 6th column and erase the last four digits you can use:

`awk -F, '{print substr($6, 0, length($6)-4) }'`

Similarly, the N-1 column can be reached by:

`awk -F, '{print substr( $(NF-1), 0, length($(NF-1))-4) }'`

**Edit:**

To only replace the values in the columns, but still print everything use:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=","; OFS=","} 
{ $6=substr($6, 0, length($6)-4); 
  $(NF-1)=substr( $(NF-1), 0,length($(NF-1))-4); 
  print $0}'
```

Comment: Hey ! how can i run this commands and both prints the other columns as well ? ?

Answer (score 1):

#### Awk based solution

Nicely formatted, portable script:

```awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS = ","  # input:  fields are separated by ,
    OFS = "," # output: fields are separated by ,
}

{
    sub(/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/, "", $6)      # remove last 4 digits from the 6th column
    sub(/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/, "", $(NF-1)) # remove last 4 digits from the n-1 column
    print
}
```

One-line, less portable version using [**gawk**](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/):

```
gawk --re-interval -F , -v OFS=, '{sub("[0-9]{4}$", "", $6); sub("[0-9]{4}$", "", $(NF-1)); print}'
```

**N.B.** The regular expression engine of the traditional **awk** doesn't support the `{n}` repetition operator, so **gawk** version 3 or older needs to be run with [`--re-interval`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Options.html). For other flavors of **awk** e.g. **nawk**, you need to explicitly repeat the regular expression as in the portable longer script from above.

#### sed based solution

```sh
sed -r 's/^(([^,]*,){5})([^,]+)[0-9]{4},(([^,]*,)*)([^,]+)[0-9]{4}(,[^,]*)$/\1\3\4\6\7/'
```

(tested with [GNU sed-4.2.2-6](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/))

Comment: cristian it looks great ! but i run it and its return me the original row .

Comment: @user2783069, I've just re-run both version and they work fine (with gawk-4.1.0-3 from Fedora 20).

Comment: Have a look : awk -F , '{sub("[0-9]{4}$", "", $6); sub("[0-9]{4}$", "", $(NF-1)); for(i=1; i<NF;i++) printf("%s,", $i); printf("%s\n", $NF)}' 1.txt 
1987,4,12,31,4,1987-12-31 00:00:00.0000000,UA,19977,UA,,631,12197,1219701,31703,HPN,White Plains, NY,NY,36,New York,22,13930,1393001,30977,ORD,Chicago\, IL,IL,17,Illinois,41,756,802,483.2,6,6,0,0,0700-0759,,,,,914,938,600.8,24,24,1,1,0900-0959,0,,0,138,156,,1,738,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,US1NJBG0005,US1ILCK0027,,,,,,,,,,,,,1987-12-31 08:09:12.0000000,519494350

Comment: i have cent os 6.2 with  gawk.x86_64 0:3.1.7-10.el6

Comment: @user2783069, run it with [`--re-interval`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Options.html).

Comment: @user2783069, if it works, a vote would be appreciated.

Comment: This solution may be fine, it will certainly work with the 1 line sample the OP provided, BUT it doesn't actually do what the OP SAID he wanted which was to `I want to find each pattern of: ****-**-** **:**:**.0000000 and erase the last 4 digits`. So if `$6` and `$(NF-1)` can contain anything that doesn't match that pattern but does end in 4 zeros then the OP is in for a surprise. By the way, the first arg for sub() is an RE so use RE delimiters (`/.../` not `"..."` - it makes a difference wrt double-parsing depending on the RE) and you could just say `print` since it'll `print $0` by default.

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks for the suggestions. As for the fragility, the questioned mentioned "If its helpful this date format is in *the 6th columns and the n-1 columns*".

Comment: Understood but what it didn't say is `EVERY 6th and N-1th column contains a date in exactly this format`. If the OPs happy with it then that's fine but I suspect he just hasn't really thought about it very much.

Comment: does the sed solution works if a line on the input contains more than two or n number of  date and time(like `1987-12-31 00:00:00.0000000`).

Comment: @AvinashRaj, as mentioned before, the answer modifies only columns 6 and n-1 as the OP requested. Though it could be made more generic.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution in Perl.

**Update - Edited to output the full CSV line with the timestamp replaced with the truncated one**

**Update 2 - Update both timestamp columns, not just the first one**

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Text::CSV;

my $CSV = Text::CSV->new();

while (my $line = readline(STDIN)) {
    $CSV->parse($line) or die "Unable to parse line '$line'";

    my @fields = $CSV->fields();

    for my $f (@fields) {
        $f =~ s/
            ^               # start of string
            (               # start capture to $1
                \d{4} -     # year
                \d{2} -     # month
                \d{2} \s+   # day
                \d{2} :     # hour
                \d{2} :     # minute
                \d{2} [.]   # second
                \d{3}       # milisecond
            )               # end capture to $1
            \d{4}           # unwanted sub-second precision
            $               # end of string
        /$1/gmsx;
    }

    $CSV->combine(@fields);
    say $CSV->string();
}
```

For example:

```
alex@yuzu:~$ cat input.txt 
1987,4,12,31,4,1987-12-31 00:00:00.0000000,UA,19977,UA,,631,12197,1219701,31703,HPN,White Plains, NY,NY,36,New York,22,13930,1393001,30977,ORD,Chicago\, IL,IL,17,Illinois,41,756,802,483.2,6,6,0,0,0700-0759,,,,,914,938,600.8,24,24,1,1,0900-0959,0,,0,138,156,,1,738,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,US1NJBG0005,US1ILCK0027,,,,,,,,,,,,,1987-12-31 08:09:12.0000000,519494350

alex@yuzu:~$ ./csv.pl < input.txt
1987,4,12,31,4,"1987-12-31 00:00:00.000",UA,19977,UA,,631,12197,1219701,31703,HPN,"White Plains"," NY",NY,36,"New York",22,13930,1393001,30977,ORD,Chicago\," IL",IL,17,Illinois,41,756,802,483.2,6,6,0,0,0700-0759,,,,,914,938,600.8,24,24,1,1,0900-0959,0,,0,138,156,,1,738,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,US1NJBG0005,US1ILCK0027,,,,,,,,,,,,,"1987-12-31 08:09:12.000",519494350
```

On a Debian-like system such as Ubuntu you should already have Perl, and you can install Text::CSV with:

```bash
$ sudo apt-get install libtext-csv-perl
```

Comment: Is it to me or this program is incomplete? It prints only the 6th column after it changing it.

Comment: Ah you're right, I misunderstood the question. I'll update the answer accordingly, thanks @CristianCiupitu :)

Comment: What about the penultimate column (n-1)?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this GNU sed command also,

```
$ sed -r 's/^.*,([^,]*)....,.*$/\1/g' file
1987-12-31 08:09:12.000
```

If you want just replacing then try this,

```
$ sed -r 's/^(.*,)([^,]*)....(,.*)$/\1\2\3/g' file
1987,4,12,31,4,1987-12-31 00:00:00.0000000,UA,19977,UA,,631,12197,1219701,31703,HPN,White Plains, NY,NY,36,New York,22,13930,1393001,30977,ORD,Chicago\, IL,IL,17,Illinois,41,756,802,483.2,6,6,0,0,0700-0759,,,,,914,938,600.8,24,24,1,1,0900-0959,0,,0,138,156,,1,738,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,US1NJBG0005,US1ILCK0027,,,,,,,,,,,,,1987-12-31 08:09:12.000,519494350
```

I think you want the the output to be like this,

```
$ grep -oP '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\....' file
1987-12-31 00:00:00.000
1987-12-31 08:09:12.000
```

**Update:**

```
$ echo '1987,4,12,31,4,1987-12-31 00:00:00.0000000,UA,19977,UA,,631,12197,1219701,31703,HPN,White Plains, NY,NY,36,New York,22,13930,1393001,30977,ORD,Chicago\, IL,IL,17,Illinois,41,756,802,483.2,6,6,0,0,0700-0759,,,,,914,938,600.8,24,24,1,1,0900-0959,0,,0,138,156,,1,738,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,US1NJBG0005,US1ILCK0027,,,,,,,,,,,,,1987-12-31 08:09:12.0000000,519494350' | sed -r 's/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\....)..../\1/g'
1987,4,12,31,4,1987-12-31 00:00:00.000,UA,19977,UA,,631,12197,1219701,31703,HPN,White Plains, NY,NY,36,New York,22,13930,1393001,30977,ORD,Chicago\, IL,IL,17,Illinois,41,756,802,483.2,6,6,0,0,0700-0759,,,,,914,938,600.8,24,24,1,1,0900-0959,0,,0,138,156,,1,738,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,US1NJBG0005,US1ILCK0027,,,,,,,,,,,,,1987-12-31 08:09:12.000,519494350
```

Comment: but it just print me the n - 1 columns , i need to edit the entire file . can you know how ?

Comment: Oh, you want to replace `1987-12-31 08:09:12.0000000` with `1987-12-31 08:09:12.000` and leave the other text as it is.

Comment: I want to replace each occurrence of date time with 6 digits in the milliseconds .

Comment: what you wrote with the sed -r its great !! but i need every occurrence of date time with 6 digits in the milliseconds to have 3 digits  how can i do it ??

Comment: did you want only the occurences in milliseconds as the first command output?

Comment: @user2783069 Again, as I stated above, post a FEW lines of sample input and expected output, not just 1!

Comment: Whats not clear ? look at my question . i just want to edit my file and erase the last 3 digits in the milliseconds in each datetime in my file.

Comment: @user2783069 you mean this `grep -oP '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\....' file`

Comment: @user2783069 It's not clear what your input might look like, what similar but undesirable patterns might appear in your input, and what your output format should be. I know you think you've stated your problem clearly but every person trying to answer your question so far has misunderstood your requirements so that should tell you something.